# Proof inequality in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n).$ I wanted to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|-\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2)}\geq 0$$

I spent some times to show that but I am not sure if there are some inequalities that I have to use to show that or it can proved without it

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Define $|x_{i}|=a_{i}\geq 0$ then we precisely want,
$$\boxed{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})^2\geq \sum_{i}^{n} a^{2}_{i}}$$
But we know,
$$\boxed{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{2}_{i}+2(\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_{i}a_{j})}$$
But
$$2(\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} a_{i}a_{j})\geq 0(\text{think on it Why?})$$ so done!!!
Equality for $a_{i}=0$ for all but one $i=1,2,...,n$
$\blacksquare$
Hope it will help!!

Question for You: Can You prove Equality Case of this problem Explicitly?